# Enabling GUI on Vagrant VirtualBox - undefined local variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I'm new to vagrant/homestead, and I'm trying to debug the box that was created using vagrant up as the connection is on a timeout loop.  I'm trying to enable the GUI.  I've tried adding the config from the vagrant site and every variation of it to my vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.gui = true
end
```

But whenever this is in there and I run vagrant up or reload, it just returns `"Message: undefined local variable or method 'config' for main:Object"`

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you are using latest Vagrant 1.6.3 and VirtualBox 4.3.12. The block looks fine.

Comment: Try placing the statement inside the "homestead.rb" file inside the "scripts" directory.  That is where most of the VirtualBox settings are defined.

Comment: Please post a gist with the whole Vagrantfile

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recently I had the same problem, in my case this is because I put this code outside the main vagrant config block, try to put in the proper place like in example. First line define local variable `config` which used inside the block:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  // other configs

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.gui = true
  end

end
```